# How to run async method within flutter app?

Tags: flutter, service, background-process

I want to load data continuously from server when app is start and stop it when app is closed.
So, how to achieve  this ?
for example in flutter

1. start app.
2. method is start to running, whatever widget on screen .
3. close app.
4. method stop.

Answer (score 1):

you can execute your funtion on bakcground.

people are usually use `workmanager` package. here : https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

another option, you also can use [flutter_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate)

```
final isolate = await FlutterIsolate.spawn(your-asycn-funtion, "hello2");
```

Comment: I want to go as broadcasting not a background service

Comment: you said that **whatever widget on screen** , thats why i suggest to run function on background.   if you only  has 1 screen, just call the function on initState.  but if you have multiple screen, running on background are one of the solution

Comment: background means run method always when app will terminate

Comment: i have no experience in `workmanager`. But for `flutter isolate`, as far as I know, the function is only executed while the application is running.

Comment: more about `isolate` class : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html

Comment: I coming from android, iOS setup is deficult for me, is there any example for flutter isolate?